# Swift Mapkit max min zoom

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, mapkit

I can't seem to find the best answer to my question SO.

I have this code that is "OK" but not idea

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, regionDidChangeAnimated animated: Bool) {

        print(mapView.camera.altitude)
        if mapView.camera.altitude < 800.00 && !modifyingMap
        {
            modifyingMap = true
            mapView.camera.altitude = 800.00
            modifyingMap = false
        }
    }
```

I would like to limit a user's max and min zoom to my map in my app.

any links to the SO answer are greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Add some code to analyse

Comment: https://github.com/johndpope/MKMapViewZoom/blob/master/MKMapView%2BZoomLevel.m

Comment: Take a look here. Swift 5, iOS 13 and later
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68293072/6292624

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use the `mapView:regionDidChangeAnimated:` delegate method to listen for region change events, and if the region is wider/narrower than your maximum/minimum region, set it back to the max/min region with `setRegion:animated:` to indicate to your user that they can't zoom out/in that far.

e.g.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, regionDidChangeAnimated animated: Bool) {
    let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(mapView.region.center.latitude, mapView.region.center.longitude)
    var span = mapView.region.span
    if span.latitudeDelta < 0.002 { // MIN LEVEL
        span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.002, 0.002)
    } else if span.latitudeDelta > 0.003 { // MAX LEVEL
        span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.003, 0.003)
    }
    let region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(coordinate, span)
    mapView.setRegion(region, animated:true)
}
```

Comment: Thanks! that's what i needed!

Comment: Outdated for iOS 13

Answer (score 5):

Try this out:

```
 mapView.cameraZoomRange = MKMapView.CameraZoomRange(
            minCenterCoordinateDistance: 1000, // Minimum zoom value
            maxCenterCoordinateDistance: 10000) // Max zoom value
```

Comment: Only available in iOS 13 or newer.